# Magento - Displaying custom attribute in accounts area (front-end)

Tags: magento, custom-attributes, account

I have used this module creator to get an custom attribute (which takes the type 'file'). 
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

This works and can be seen in the admin area. I also have other custom attributes for customers which I have used this tutorial to create:
http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes

This also works. The reason I used the module creator was because I was unsure of how to make the input type as 'file'.

The attributes created through the fontis tutorial can be displayed as needed on the front end (which was only needed in the registration form).

The problem I'm having is in the custom area in the logged in accounts area on the front end. What I need is to retrieve the value of the 'file' attributes which was created in the module creator. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to display these please? I have tried getAttributeName but this is not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post the code from your custom module we could help you more.

Meanwhile, here is some info that could help you:

- Whenever you store something in the DB using a module, there is a Model class (that allows you to access the necessary data)
- You can find the class name by looking in your modules `etc/config.xml` file
- In the file look for section named `<models>`
- The sub nodes of `<models>` is the name of the namespace (see below)
- The sub node of your 'namespace' called `<class>` contains the rest of the info you will need
- Next you need to call the Model with `Mage::getModel('namespace/class_name')->load($id);` to get a collection of all the custom attribute records that are in the system

To break this down in to manageable pieces:

Let's assume this is what your `config.xml` contains:

```
<models>
    <customattribute> // this is your namespace
         <class>Mycompany_Customattribute_Model</class> //this tells you wher to find your model files
          <resourceModel>customattribute_resource</resourceModel>
    </customattribute>

...
</models>
```

This means that your 'namespace' is 'customattribute'.

Next you need to find the file that contains your Model.

In this case we look at the `<class>` node to give us the file location (in this case `app/code/local/Mycompany/Customattrbute/Model`), now we need to go there and see the file that is there (let's say it's called 'File.php')

To get all the data we call the follwoing function:

```
Mage::getModel('customattribute/file')->load();
```

This will give us all the data.

If we want to narrow it down we can use the following function:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customattribute/file')->addFieldToFilter('name_of_filed_in_db', 'value_we_want');
```